# Can oracle handle SERVER = POOLED (DRCP) and SERVER = DEDICATED clients simultaneously?

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration, oracle-11g, pool

I run a PHP application that uses an Oracle 11g instance as it's backend.  We currently connect with DEDICATED as our type but we're having trouble scaling.

As such, I suggested to the DBA we implement DRCP connection pooling as this seems to be best (only?) way to handle in a php environment.

Problem is other applications / vendors also connect to this same db and DBA is concerned with switching everyone to pooled as it'd be a big testing effort.  Also we'd have different userids so I don't even think pooled makes sense in that context if we all had to be in the same pool.

So, my question is can the server simultaneously service clients that want to connect via DEDICATED and me via POOLED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, no problem. You can even connect as a single db user in both POOLED and DEDICATED mode. The DEDICATED connection is 'easy' for the database engine, because it simply starts a separate process, which ends when the session is ended (it doesn't reuse anything).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Along the same lines, can you have multiple pools (ie: App 1 pool, App 2's pool, etc.)?